# java installers and uninstallers return error 1602

Tags: windows-registry, windows-installer

I am trying to remove java 6 32 bit and install java 7 64 bit, but after initially having the uninstaller open and execute successfully, asking me to plan a full removal after a reboot, the uninstaller did not come back, and neither does executing it again work.

I've tried using revouninstaller to remove the old java, which seems to be successful, but java 7's installer still won't execute.

When I execute the offline installer, it asks for administrator privileges, loads up the MSI, and then vanishes. After consulting the event viewer I found these entries from MsiInstaller:

> Product: Java(TM) 7 Update 2 (64-bit) -- Installation operation failed.

and

> Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: Java(TM) 7 Update 2 (64-bit). Product Version: 7.0.20. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Oracle. Installation success or error status: 1602.

All I know is that error 1602 is supposed to mean user cancelled the installation, which leads me to believe either UAC isn't working correctly (seems to work fine though), or there is some registry entry blocking the MSI installer (though I've checked manually).

Comment: See if this Microsoft fixit utility helps..http://support.microsoft.com/mats/Program_Install_and_Uninstall

Comment: I ran it and it says there were no problems found. Says it's not related to the registry. Installer still closes. Thank you for trying though!

Comment: Try the Java online installer from the java site

Comment: Didn't work either.. Probably just gonna disregard it, I was looking for an excuse to reinstall my PC anyway, so this is just another reason to do it.

Comment: Still weird that there's no good way to solve this, it's really hard to clean out all the remaints java leaves behind it seems

Comment: Its probably not a java issue, more like windows corruption. Cave and Pave baby!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, on a second thought, instead of doing the reinstall, I just went on digging more in the registry.
I just searched for 'java' and deleted all the entries that I deemed relevant to java runtime (so not the javascript, msjava, javavm, etc) entries, and it worked!

I got java runtime 7 installed now, works like a charm.

So if anyone else runs into this, might be worth trying to dig out the registry manually!

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem when I removed and tried to re-install JRE 7.

I deleted the key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\JavaSoft\FIUCancel` to allow re-install.

Comment: This did it for me!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a later update. The uninstall would close and "Product: Java(TM) 6 Update 33 -- Removal failed." and "Removal success or error status: 1602." would appear in the event log.

I ran the Microsoft Fixit utility at http://support.microsoft.com/mats/Program_Install_and_Uninstall (thanks Moab). That allowed me to select Java 6 for uninstallation and the uninstallation completed successfully.

I also used the Fixit utility to remove Java 7 Update 6 which had the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

This is an old thread, but I came across it while searching for a solution to the same problem ... 11 years later ...

The issue is the installer software bug #35961435. Just like me, you are probably using the well-known format c:\Program Files\java\jre1.8.0_401 (My case) to keep multiple versions organized.

The solution, believe or not, is simply using a different path... For example:

c:\Program Files\java\jre180_401  (64-bits)

c:\Program Files (x86)\java\jre180_401 (32-bits)

Using the format I copied above, I was able to install the software without any issue.

The same is described in Oracle Support note:

1602 Error While Installing JRE Part of JDK Windows Installer in Custom Location (Doc ID 2994526.1)

I hope that helps.
Regards